# Cannot configure alsa-utils on TI am335x

Tags: yocto

I am currently trying to build an embedded linux image for TI AM335x using Yocto.

I downloaded the `meta-ti` layer from `git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-ti` and I am targeting the image `image-core-base` for the machine `am335x-evm`.

Unluckily I get an error during `do_configure` phase for recipe `alsa-utils_1.0.28.bb`:

> ERROR: Task 2030
>   (/home/morix/devel/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-multimedia/alsa/alsa-utils_1.0.28.bb,
>   do_configure) failed with exit code '1'

Looking at the detailed log (that you can review [here](http://pastebin.com/HwT0Y6Yx)), I find the following error:

```
[...]
checking form.h presence... yes
checking for form.h... yes
checking for new_panel in -lpanelw... no
configure: error: panelw library not found
Configure failed. The contents of all config.log files follows to aid debugging
[...]
```

So the problem seems the lack of `panelw`... After some short investigations I discovered that `panelw` is provided by `ncurses` library and I checked that `ncurses` is included in the image... and it is! So, what's wrong?

Comment: I've hit this too, building for sama5d3xek. I dug a tiny bit deeper and filed a bug at https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by http://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/80727/ that will get merged for 1.7.

You can also use a bpappend until then:
(recipes-core/ncurses/ncurses_5.9.bbappend)

```
do_configure_prepend() {
        # The --enable-pc-files requires PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR existed
        mkdir -p ${PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem.
This workaround worked for me:

```
bitbake alsa-tools -c cleansstate +

bitbake ncurses -c cleansstate +

bitbake alsa-tools +

bitbake myImage
```

Good luck.